# How to get all filtered value in a record by using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a field with the value in a table like below (two records).

```
|     field
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| [{"id":"8a688d70-d881-11ea-b999-3b32356f3dce","supplierName":"t1"},{"id":"8a688d70-deeq-3221-cdee-3b32356f3dc1","supplierName":"t2"]
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| [{"id":"8a688d70-323s-11ea-2123-3b32356f1111","supplierName":"t3"}]
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    ...
```

When I use the SQL

```
select substring(field1, 9, 36)
  FROM table
```

I  get the records

```
8a688d70-d881-11ea-b999-3b32356f3dce
8a688d70-323s-11ea-2123-3b32356f1111
```

Now, Is there any way to get all the id value in a record?
NOTE, maybe one record had mutiple id values.
Ideal result should be like below.

```
|———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————— 
|8a688d70-d881-11ea-b999-3b32356f3dce, 8a688d70-deeq-3221-cdee-3b32356f3dc1
|————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
|8a688d70-323s-11ea-2123-3b32356f1111
|————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

Comment: database version?  how many ids will be in a record at most?

Comment: See the manual under JSON functions

Comment: no limit for id in a record. only need to find all of them. should I use regx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON_EXTRACT` of mySql.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(field, "$[*].id") AS field FROM table
```

Comment: thx！ but i think GROUP_CONCAT is not the answer. It will only get one record. I need to get all id value in a record.

Comment: You can use multiple column in `GROUP_CONCAT`. Or you can use mix of CONCAT + GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: i have updated the question to make it clear. I am not sure your solution. thx